# How to return the reponse.statuscode

Tags: vb.net, email, task, sendgrid

I having an error on Response.StatusCode, it prompted me "Value of "HttpStatusCode" cannot be converted to 'Task(Of HttpStatusCode)'", any clue?

```
  Public Async Function Execute(ByVal MailFrom As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Task(Of HttpStatusCode))

    Try
        Dim client = New SendGridClient("apikey")
        Dim from = New EmailAddress("ABC@gmail.com.my", "ABC") '' Login Email and Display Its name in mail,on Inbox
        Dim subject = "Hello World"
        Dim sto = New EmailAddress("James@gmail", "James")

        strBody = "<span style='font-family:Calibri;font-size:small'>"
        strBody = strBody & "Testing Email here"
        strBody = strBody & "</span>"

        Dim plainTextContent = ""
        Dim htmlContent = strBody
        Dim msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, sto, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent)

        Dim Response = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(False)
        Return Response.StatusCode

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: `... As Task(Of HttpStatusCode)`

Comment: ...Execute says it should return a `Task(Of Task(Of HttpStatusCode))`  - is that what you intended?  It means the object after the Return statement needs to be `Task(Of HttpStatusCode)`, but you gave it just `HttpStatusCode`.  My guess is that the proper syntax of Execute's return type should just be `Task(Of HttpStatusCode)`.

Comment: i try to change it to As Task(Of HttpStatusCode) but the system auto default back to "As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Task(Of HttpStatusCode))".. any clue?

Comment: Add `Imports System.Threading.Tasks` and change the return value back to `...As Task(Of HttpStatusCode)`.